# iOS keyboard closing on keyup

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, soft-keyboard, iphone-softkeyboard

Re-Asked to bump this back up the list of questions...

Comment: Are you losing the `focus` by any chance ?

Comment: @RayonDabre , On a desktop/laptop, no. On a mobile device, yes.

Comment: Can you provide the executable so that one could debug it..

Comment: @RayonDabre With pleasure. See edited question